# how to read two input files using sed processing through the bash loop?

Tags: bash, sed

Very beginner in bash, already I wrote a small script looping through all the *.txt files and processing the *.txt as an input to a perl script.

Single file as an input

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

for i in *.txt
do
  SAMPLE=$(echo ${i} | sed "s/.txt//") 
  echo ${SAMPLE}.txt

time /home/sunn/data/softwares/evaluation/msa/pal2nal.v14/pal2nal.pl ${SAMPLE}.txt -output paml > ${SAMPLE}.paml.txt
done
```

Actual command for running perl script (2 files as input)

```
    pal2nal.pl  OG0012884_out.fa OG0012884_out.txt -output paml > OG0012884_paml.txt
```

Two files as a input ? I got struck..

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

for i in *.txt 
do
  SAMPLE=$(echo ${i} | sed "s/.txt//" | "s/.fa//") 
  echo ${SAMPLE}.txt 

time /home/sunn/data/softwares/evaluation/msa/pal2nal.v14/pal2nal.pl ${SAMPLE}.fa ${SAMPLE}.txt -output paml > ${SAMPLE}.paml.txt
done
```

Comment: What's the problem? Please explain what you are trying to do, and how you "got stuck". It helps if you provide example input files and your expected output.

Comment: The perl script needs two input files, *.txt and *.fa. I only loop through only one specific set of files, as subjecting *.txt to a perl script as input. In here, the perl script asks for additional files. How do I show in the bash script ?

Comment: Actual command for running perl script , showed in the post.

Comment: Yes, I can read your post. I can't guess what you're doing though, which is why I asked for clarification. Please [put updates into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/644909/edit) so it's easy for everyone to find and read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the variable several times.

You don't need to call `sed`, parameter expansion can remove the extension, too.

```
for txt in *_out.txt ; do
    sample=${txt%.txt}
    out=${sample%_out}
    pal2nal.pl "$sample".fa "$sample".txt -output paml > "$out"_paml.txt
done
```

You might add a check that the other file exists:

```
    if [[ ! -e $sample.fa ]] ; then
        echo "$sample.fa missing, skipped." >&2
        continue
    fi
```